# SQL where clause with multiple condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

In my data base table I have some value like above image.

I want to check some conditions in my where clause.

I want to check by URL

1. `DemoOrPaid=PAID and ValidUpto=NULL  =>  then Return 1`
   2.`DemoOrPaid=PAID and ValidUpto=(NOT NULL) then compare with current date and check if ValidUpto<=GETDATE() => then Return 1`
2. `DemoOrPaid=DEMO and ValidUpto=NULL => then Return 0`
3. `DemoOrPaid=DEMO and ValidUpto=(NOT NULL) then compare with current date and check if ValidUpto<=GETDATE() =>  then Return 0`

Comment: What to return in 2. and 4. if respective condition is not met?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return some computed column, then you can use something like this:

```
select
    case
        when DemoOrPaid = 'PAID' and ValidUpto is null then 1
        when DemoOrPaid = 'PAID' and ValidUpto is not null and ValidUpto <= getdate() then 1
        when DemoOrPaid = 'DEMO' and ValidUpto is null then 1
        else 0
    end
```

It's actually a bit unclear what do you want to return in cases not covered by your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return all the rows that match.

```
select * from Table where 
(DemoOrPaid='PAID' and ValidUpto is NULL) or 
(DemoOrPaid='PAID' and ValidUpto is NOT NULL and ValidUpto<=GETDATE()) or 
(DemoOrPaid='DEMO' and ValidUpto is NULL) or 
(DemoOrPaid='DEMO' and ValidUpto is NULL and ValidUpto<=GETDATE())
```

Comment: I write  Declare @iCount as int
 set @iCount=(select COUNT(Company_ID) from tbl_AdminCompanyMaster where URL=LTRIM(RTRIM(@URL))
     and
     (DemoOrPaid='PAID' and ValidUpto is NULL) or 
     (DemoOrPaid='PAID' and ValidUpto is NOT NULL and ValidUpto<=GETDATE()) or 
     (DemoOrPaid='DEMO' and ValidUpto is NULL) or 
     (DemoOrPaid='DEMO' and ValidUpto is NULL and ValidUpto<=GETDATE())
      
     )
      print(@iCount) I pass **RAGA** as a parameter of **@URL** but it return 2 ,but as per data it should return 1